# Sencha GPL license is must?

Tags: ios, extjs, sencha-touch

I am independent developer, i developed a small application which holds basic sencha components (Not Charts) with some phonegap features. For android there is no issue in uploading my app in playstore. For IOS is there is any concerns ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GPL license essentially states that you can use code for free ONLY IF you are building an open-source application. If you're not building an open-source app, then you have to buy the commercial license.

If you need clarification, contact Sencha's sales/licensing team.

Comment: For clarification, Sencha Touch does have a free commercial license (Ext JS does not). But there is a legal difference between the GPL "Open Source" and GPL "Commercial" licenses, so be sure you contact Sencha if you need more info.

Answer (score 1):

You can check Sencha license requirements here:
https://enterprise.dejacode.com/license_library/Demo/sencha-commercial/#license-requirements

Hope it helps.